# Why does latex say my package is not found?

Tags: packages

I installed the basic LaTeX edition for Mac. I used the package manager `ttlmgr` to install `relsize` and `bbm`.

For some reason the package `relsize` is found but not `bbm`...

Any idea what goes wrong? (note: I run `pdflatex myfile.tex` in the screenshot)

[image]

Another thing I noted: I actually created by hand `bbm/bbm.sty` (downloaded) because it didn't exist. There were

```
./2019basic/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/bbm
./2019basic/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/bbm
```

though, but things didn't work before or after adding this. And weirdly it doesn't "find the package" but there is a `bbm.sty` file... I'm confused

Comment: You seem to have installed BasicTeX, which only include a few packages. You need to use TeX Live Utility to install also `bbm` (but I'm not sure you want to use it, as it only provides bitmap fonts).

Comment: @egreg but what is the standard way to install something / why does tlmgr not work? Also it seems I have /Library/TeX (and probably lots of symlinks there) so should I try to install "by hand" the bbm.sty file there?

Comment: If you can run either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you might want to use `unicode-math`, which supports double-struck symbols. If not, you might want to use one of the options from `mathalfa`, or `dsfont`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and what it worked was to also install:

```
 tlmgr install collection-fontsextra
```

It seems that the package names are misleading.